# Duplicates values in drop downlist Issue

Tags: java, android

I have a small problem when I read value in spinner I found a duplicates values like the below images:

[image]
[image]

and this is the related code part:

```
                opertor = new String[size];
                amoutnvalue = new String[size];
                for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                    long amount = smsListitem.get(x).getPrice();
                    Keyword keyword = smsListitem.get(x).getKeyword();
                    Network network = smsListitem.get(x).getNetwork();
                    phoneNum = smsListitem.get(x).getShortcode().toString();
                    amoutnvalue[x] = "" + amount;
                    if (LngID == 0) {
                        String opert = network.getAr();
                        opertor[x] = opert;
                        //  hm.put(opert, opert);
                    } else if (LngID == 1) {
                        String operten = network.getEn();
                        opertor[x] = operten;
                        //  hm.put(operten, operten);
                    }

                }
```

and this is the full method:

```
private void loadSmsData(List<Sm> smsListitem) {
        try {

            String url = "http://alkhair.homedns.org:53761/SmartApps/publicImages/" + Proj_ID + ".png";
            Log.d("Banner Url", url);
            //ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, smsimageView, options);
            Utils.loadImage(smsimageView, url);

            int size = smsListitem.size();
            if (smsListitem == null) {
                amount_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                net_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                smsnotfound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sendbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                smsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                          //--------------------------------make credit card defal
                bankLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                visaLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                smsBtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#067a3d"));
                bankBtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#067a3d"));
                visaBtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                //----------------------------------layout
                smsBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                bankBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                visaBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#067a3d"));
            } else if (smsListitem.size() <= 0) {
                amount_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                net_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               smsnotfound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sendbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //--------------------------------make credit card defal
                smsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bankLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                visaLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                smsBtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#067a3d"));
                bankBtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#067a3d"));
                visaBtn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                //----------------------------------layout
                smsBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                bankBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                visaBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#067a3d"));
            } else {

                opertor = new String[size];
                amoutnvalue = new String[size];
                for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                    long amount = smsListitem.get(x).getPrice();
                    Keyword keyword = smsListitem.get(x).getKeyword();
                    Network network = smsListitem.get(x).getNetwork();
                    phoneNum = smsListitem.get(x).getShortcode().toString();
                    amoutnvalue[x] = "" + amount;
                    if (LngID == 0) {
                        String opert = network.getAr();
                        opertor[x] = opert;
                        //  hm.put(opert, opert);
                    } else if (LngID == 1) {
                        String operten = network.getEn();
                        opertor[x] = operten;
                        //  hm.put(operten, operten);
                    }
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, opertor);

                operspiner.setAdapter(adapter);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapteramount = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, amoutnvalue);

                amountspiner.setAdapter(adapteramount);

                amountspiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        SpinerItemAmount = amountspiner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        post = position;

                    }
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    }
                });


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
    }
```

and this is the Println message for `smsListItem`:

```
2021-11-25 14:17:45.950 15903-15903/com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity I/System.out: SMSListItem: [com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@8cab674, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@39f379d, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@e2ab412, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@2f857e3, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@b16c5e0, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@43cb099, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@afbff5e, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@5ce8f3f]
2021-11-25 14:17:45.953 15903-15903/com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity I/chatty: uid=11246(com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity) identical 6 lines
2021-11-25 14:17:45.953 15903-15903/com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity I/System.out: SMSListItem: [com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@8cab674, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@39f379d, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@e2ab412, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@2f857e3, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@b16c5e0, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@43cb099, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@afbff5e, com.appgain.BeetElKhairCharity.ApiJsonModel.emgercyJsonModel.Sm@5ce8f3f]
```

Comment: try to print your smsListitem, it might has some duplicate data so it displaying duplicate records

Comment: @D_K could you check edits please :D

Comment: Your smsListItem contains 8 items, but from the image you should have 4 {10, 20, 50, 100}, that's means you inserted items twice, so check where you update it and make sure to clear it before add new items

Comment: @AmrDeveloper thanks a lot Amr for your support I have already solved it :)

Comment: you are welcome Mahmoud, good luck